# Rails Associations (many to many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-models

I'm working with Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord and trying to realize my database structure.

What I want is something link this:

| User |
| --- |
| id |
| username |

| License |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| ActiveLicenses |
| --- |
| user_id (foreign key to user.id) |
| license_id (foreign key to license.id) |
| expiration |

And this is how far I've got:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :active_licenses
    has_many :licenses, :through => :active_licenses

    validates :keycloak_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
class License < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :active_licenses
    has_many :users, :through => :active_licenses

    validates :name, presence: true
end
class ActiveLicense < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :licenses

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :license_id, presence: true
end
```

```
class AddUsersAndLicenses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.text "keycloak_id"

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :licenses do |t|
      t.text "name"

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :active_licenses do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :license
      t.text "expiration"

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Creating records works just fine with `user = User.create(username: "my_username")`, `License.create(name: "first_license")` `License.create(name: "second_license")`. Now I want to link the user to the licenses: `user.licenses = License.all`. This failes with the error message: "NameError (uninitialized constant User::Licenses)"

Anyone here who can help me?

Comment: isn't `belongs_to` in `ActiveLicense` should be in singular form? reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Answer (score 0):

ActiveLicense should have many licenses and licenses should belong_to ActiveLicense.

Try making your model look like this and restart your console / server

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :active_licenses
    has_many :licenses, :through => :active_licenses

    validates :keycloak_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
class License < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :active_license


    validates :name, presence: true
end
class ActiveLicense < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :licenses

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :license_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: just edited fixing typo in active_license, let me know if that works!

Comment: can you mark it as answered if this helped you?

Comment: This is not quiet it for my use case. What I want is a n:m association between User and License with an association attribute called expiration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was a typo mistake at `belongs_to`.

This did the trick for me:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :active_licenses
    has_many :licenses, :through => :active_licenses

    validates :keycloak_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
class License < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :active_licenses
    has_many :users, :through => :active_licenses

    validates :name, presence: true
end
class ActiveLicense < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :license

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :license_id, presence: true
end
```